# Android DatePickerDialog extra/redundant invocation

Tags: android, datepicker

I've simple problem with `DatePickerDialog` functionality. I've an edit text view, when clicked pops-up a `DatePickerDialog` as shown below,

```
        mNoteDateTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            currentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            currentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(NewNoteActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    yearFinal = i;
                    monthFinal = i1 + 1;
                    dayFinal = i2;

                    Log.v(TAG, "\n" + " year: " + yearFinal + "\n" +
                            "Month:" + monthFinal + "\n" +
                            "Day:" + dayFinal);
                }
            }, currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay);

            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

The problem is, after I select the date and click on the Done button in the dialog, I see Log.v() output twice as,

```
04-18 00:50:03.832 15601-15601/myexample.com.notes V/MyActivity:  year: 2018
Month:5
Day:19
04-18 00:50:03.832 15601-15601/myexample.com.notes V/MyActivity:  year: 2018
Month:5
Day:19
```

I can't figure out why double output instead of once?

Comment: you check with a break point and debugging

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this it shows log only once ..
on button click

```
  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Demo.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            mTvDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                            Log.d("Date To",mTvDate.getText().toString());
                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
            //below line disable old date.
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```